# Cannot get Bitmap from File

Tags: java, android, file, bitmap

I cannot retrieve bitmap from the file to which i have written the bitmap.
There is no error showing.But image is not displaying correctly.
I converted bitmap to bytes and then stored in the internal cache

### Getting image from camera

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File photo = new File(
        Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
        "pic.jpg");
img = Uri.fromFile(photo);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, img);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

### Writting image to file

```
                Bitmap takenImage =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getPath());   
File folder = getCacheDir();
                    File myFile = new File(folder, "myImage.bmp");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(img.getPath());
                    byte[] image = new byte[fis.available()];
                    fos.write(image);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    fis.close();
```

### Reading Bitmap

```
File folder = getCacheDir();
File myFile = new File(folder, "myImage.bmp");
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
imgv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: Confirm first if there is really an image in your Picture Directory associated with your filename.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
```

try to convert bitmap like this

Answer (score 0):

You are createing image file twice and may be as per my opinion, your code will be look like **below**:-

```
File myFile = new File( Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
    "pic.jpg");
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
imgv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

-Pardon me  for my poor explanation but if it is still not working you can share or ask again for the help